# Git commit but keep current index and working tree?

Tags: git

Often I'm in the following situation: I'm in the middle of a complicated maneuver and I want to try out two or more ways of proceeding from here. So I might add-and-commit and now I can try out my various strategies from this point, on one or more branches.

But here's the problem: I don't want to lose track of what I've changed so far on this branch with respect to `HEAD`. Why? Well, in the IDE where I'm coding, there are really helpful "change bars" in the margin of the code editor that mark all the staged and unstaged changes. I don't want to lose those change bars. And what they are responding to, in effect, is the `diff` between the working tree and `HEAD`.

So you see, I'd like to save all my work so as to have a stable point to return to later, if needed, but I don't want this to affect the state of `HEAD`, the index, and the working tree. I want, in effect, to make a commit that is "just a copy", without altering anything else about the universe.

Here's a diagram. I've got this:

```
A -- B -- C -- (mybranch) [and I've edited files X, Y, and Z with respect to C]
```

I want this:

```
             D? something that preserves the state of files X, Y, and Z
            /
A -- B -- C  -- (mybranch) [and X, Y, and Z are still _modified_ with respect to C]
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is *copy* the state of things into a commit, without effectively checking out that commit. Is there a command that does this?

What I've found so far is this sort of thing:

```
git switch -c temp
git commit -m 'hold my place just in case'
git switch -
git restore --source temp --worktree --staged -- .
```

But I don't honestly like it; it feels risky, somehow. What I'd prefer, I think, is some form of `git stash push` that doesn't alter the state of the index and working tree.

Comment: To clarify, you have some modified files that are staged, and some that aren't yet, and you want to get back to this state? (Or remain in this state?)

Comment: @TTT Actually it happens that they are all staged.

Comment: Would commit, followed by `git reset --soft @~1` work? I think you'd be back where you started, but now with a commit in your reflog for whatever you want to do with it. (I have others do this regularly when I'm helping them and they have pending changes they aren't ready to commit yet. Usually theirs aren't even staged, so I have them use --mixed instead.)

Comment: Well, I certainly hadn't thought of using the reflog as "storage" for a reference to a commit.

Comment: When it's me, I usually just leave it in the reflog in case I mess something up and I need to go back to it later, which I'm comfortable doing. For others I will typically have them create a branch (e.g. `wip/some-feature`) on the temp commit before resetting back. They can delete the branch later when they know they no longer need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers were interesting and inspiring, but in the end I went with the following alias from https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias:

```
snapshot = !git stash push --include-untracked --message \"snapshot: $(date)\" && git stash apply \"stash@{0}\" --index
```

This creates a stash and then immediately restores both the index and the working tree. You can't tell outwardly that anything happened, yet there is now a viable well-marked commit that can easily be retrieved if needed.

Answer (score 3):

`git commit` keeps the current index and working tree, the only other thing it does is update HEAD to point at the new commit.

`git stash -k` makes a couple of new commits from your current index and work tree, but you don't need the interim-work-tree snapshot, skip it by either doing an ordinary commit and re-hanging the `HEAD` label,

```
git commit
git tag snap
git reset --soft @^
```

or just do it directly,

```
git tag snap $(git commit-tree -p @ -m snap `git write-tree`)
```

and then you can cherry-pick and discard the snapshot whenever you want.

Comment: Good use of a tag!

Answer (score 1):

`git stash` actually has subcommands that allow to "stash without clearing the changes" :

```
git stash create       # creates the same commits as 'git stash push",
                       # but don't store them
git stash store <sha>  # adds commit <sha> in the stash list
```

You can create an alias :

```
git config --global alias.snap '! git stash store $(git stash create)'
```

Check `git help stash` for more details (for example: you can add `git stash store -m "..."` to add a custom message ...)

---

The upside with respect to `git commit-tree $(git write-tree)` is : `git stash create` also saves the unstaged content on modified files.

---

Also note that `git stash store` basically does [`git update-ref refs/stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref) with a few standardized options, and that the list of stashes is just the reflog for `refs/stash`.

If you want to store these kind of snapshots under another name, you can use :

```
git update-ref -m "spapshot while working on '$commitmsg'" --create-reflog \
        refs/snap $(git stash create)
```

and inspect `git reflog snap` to have a list of your "snaps".

Comment: Once again, I don't understand the documentation. The docs say that `create` and `store` are not what one wants, suggesting that `push` was intended instead. But in that case, why is there no way to make `push` behave the way `create` plus `store` works?

Comment: @matt : the doc states "This is intended to be useful for scripts" ;) (which is more or less our case)

Comment: There are 3 verbs `create`, `store` and `push`, IMHO the "you probably want push" part is to guide people to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You could also execute the plumbing commands [`git write-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-write-tree) and [`git commit-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) directly:

```
git branch rememberme $(git commit-tree $(git write-tree) -p HEAD)
```

Can be easily wrapped in an alias to make the branch name a user input or use `push` instead to create a history of intermediate steps.